# HighCharts downloaded Legends are overlapping in ie11

Tags: highcharts

Legends in the downloaded chart are overlapping in ie 11.i tried keeping itemDistance:20 in legend area of the chart.
i am able to see the item distance in the chart in the website, but the legends are getting overlapped in the downloaded png image.

Comment: Your question is broad, can you show what you already tried?

Comment: hi Pols,i have tried with the following code,
             legend: {
                enabled: true,
                layout: 'horizontal',
                align: 'center',
                verticalAlign: 'bottom',
                borderWidth: 0,
                margin: 10

            },
            exporting: {
                enabled: true
            },